# How can I add a backgorund image that fits my content?

Tags: html, css, background-image, bootstrap-5

I am developing my friend's windsurf club website. The problem I have right now is, I am trying to give it a lavish look, and behind the `<h1>` and `<h2>` elements, I want my background image to lie. Right now, I have put the image and set the repeat to no-repeat but it is far apart from my content. Is it something about bootstrap? How can I correct it? The thing that I am trying to achieve is similar to these examples: [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ0b4.jpg) [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKamI.jpg) But right now it looks likes this: [mywebsite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqEqL.jpg)

```css
body {
  background-color: #B1B2FF;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-brand,
.nav-link {
  color: #EEF1FF;
}

.addbg {
  background-image: url("images/24.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 1%;
}

#top h2 {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif Gujarati', serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  color: #EEF1FF;
}


/* font-family: 'Noto Serif Gujarati', serif;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; */
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif+Gujarati:wght@200;300;400&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1e90402f09.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bojark Windsurf</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Ana Sayfa</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Paketlerimiz</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hakkımızda</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Top Part -->
<section id="top">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center addbg">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Bojark Windsurf</h1>
        <h2>Bambaşka Bir Deneyime Hazır Mısın?</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Bootstrap JS-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You can extend the with to 100% by using `w-100` as a css class, but I would also ensure your image is large enough to span the whole width. Your layout looks off, your image will likely be super tall in height if you span it the whole width without cutting some off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can use inner html, I think that's what I can help

```
       <div class="p-5 text-center bg-image" style="
  background-image: url('https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.webp');height: 400px;">
```

Comment: Nice, one question left. When I resize the window to be smaller, the image also changes, and at some point, it fixes and the text goes away from it. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Backgrounds lie completely in the CSS file, not the HTML file. They are inherintly behind all HTML elements. To create a background as it looks like you have done partly? I would remove the .addbg and add this line of code into the body info

background: url("images/24.jpg");

Comment: And what about when I want to create other sections on the below? I added the background-image to the body element as you've said but it will contain every part of the website. I want to use other backgrounds on the below sections that I will create.

Comment: That is not possible. A background covers the whole page. Unless you make different pages, then you can have different backgrounds.         Maybe try using Google sites or a website builder for now untill you get solid at HTML? I personally find Google sites very easy for the front end of websites, and you can imbed Google forms for orders?